# How Do I Make A Permanent, Systemwide Change to $PATH

Tags: 18.04, environment-variables

Consider, academically, that I have executed `sudo mv /bin /foo`. I didn't stop to ask questions, I took charge of my destiny and did it.

What would I have to do if I wanted to permanently change the system-wide `$PATH` to reflect this change? This includes:

- interactive shells
- non-interactive shells
- GUI logins
- system services
- sudo use

The reason I ask this, is the water is very muddy about the correct way to do this. Answers to this question variously suggest:

- editing `~/.bashrc` (won't affect e.g. `bash --norc`)
- editing `~/.profile` (only affects login shells)
- editing `/etc/environment` (doesn't affect sudo; sometimes PATH doesn't seem to be here?)

Are there other core system utilities which are likely to cause problems by trying to use some `$PATH` copy defined in yet other ways or places that I haven't covered here? How do you override `$PATH` when using sudo?

**Where does the One `$PATH` To Rule Them All live, and how do I add `/foo` to it?**

I know this has been asked a bunch of times but there are so many different questions and answers floating around and many of them are out of date or cover only certain cases.

Comment: Editing `/etc/environment` *does* change `PATH` permanently and systemwide; however `sudo` is configured to use its own `secure_path` which is unaffected by the `PATH` variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path) See [ish's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/170240)

Answer (score 1):

You probably cannot remove /bin permanently from $PATH because too many scripts will reset it, but you can do some things:

Move /bin to /foo and then symlink /foo to /bin:

Run the following as root:

```
cd /; mv bin foo; ln -s foo bin
```

(This begs the question however, if you are so intent upon having contents of /bin in /foo, why not just symlink /bin to /foo?)

Then you can set your custom PATH in /etc/rc.local.  That will get sourced at boot regardless of whether anyone is logged in.  You will need to create the file if it doesn't exist.  Systemd should pick it up.  `man systemd-rc-local-generator` for more info.

Comment: I picked it as an extreme example of a configuration change that would absolutely require a properly updated `$PATH`, no compromise would be good enough. Also, looking at that man page, it states that that generator is provided only out of compatibility for system V and its use is discouraged, and furthermore that it runs at the end of the boot process and concurrently with many other systemd targets; I don't see how setting `$PATH` here would have a systemwide effect.

Comment: I think if you wanted to completely eliminate /bin you would almost have to rebuild your own distro and literally repackage many core packages.  Look at how many times PATH and /bin occur here:    grep -r PATH /etc/init.d |grep bin     This post has more info about the role of rc.local with systemd: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479766

Answer (score 0):

I would say editing `/etc/environment` is the best "system-wide" option.

However, `sudo` uses a secure path, defined in: `/etc/sudoers`

So I would say editing these 2 (or only one of them) would be the best way for systemwide path change.

Other environment variables (for instance `JAVA_HOME`) can also be set in `/etc/environment`.