# Places to set PATH

Tags: 14.04, paths

I need to set PATH and JAVA_HOME for my Oracle java. Where I can set these environment variables in Ubuntu in general. Where is the best place to set them?

Comment: The .bashrc file in your /home/<YOU> directory can be a good place.

Comment: Not really, since this is not systemwide.

Comment: I would consider this a duplicate of --> [How Do I Make A Permanent, Systemwide Change to $PATH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140585/how-do-i-make-a-permanent-systemwide-change-to-path)

Comment: So I've added an answer to the above post. ^^^^

Comment: Yeah maybe that one covers it better..